# How do I use multiple packages, such as location and maps?

Tags: android

First of all sorry, I'm not familiar with the terminology.

I'm following the official Android tutorial and I'm already stuck on the first section of "Making Your App Location-Aware".

I'm following from the very first tutorial and I'm stuck on the first step.

This is what the tutorial says to do,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
</manifest>
```

but I already have,

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package=com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

I'm confused as what to do. I've tried just putting the package separately, e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<activity android:name="com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity">
```

But even then in MainActivity.java apparently FusedLocationProviderClient has an error - it says 'class' or 'interface' expected.

How would I go about fixing this, and how would I use, say 3 packages?

Comment: Please post your MainActivity.java code

Answer (score 2):

CommonsWare's answer is correct. However, his answer doesn't help you much. What the tutorial MEANS is to add the line:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

right after the line:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="YOUR_PACKAGENAME_HERE" >
```

You don't need to change your package name to fix the problem, just replace `com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample` with your current package name `com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity`

Warning! If you plan on publishing your app to the Play Store, use some thing other than `com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity`

A great example of a good package name for you is `com.michaelluong.myapplication`

Comment: Ah I understand packages better now, many thanks! I guess my misunderstanding was that packages were like extra information I needed to import.
I've done what you've suggested, but still FusedLocationProviderClient has an error.
In build.gradle (Module:App) I've typed:
`dependencies {
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'`
As the tutorial suggest but still no go. :(

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about fixing this, and how would I use, say 3 packages?

You can't. An app has one package name (a.k.a., application ID).

Generally, when using tutorials, you have two choices:

1. Follow them to the letter, or
2. Do your own thing in parts, relying upon your experience to bridge between what the tutorial suggests and what you are actually doing

In your case, I suggest you choose option #1. What you have already has issues (while `com.example.user.myapplication` is a fine package name, `com.example.user.myapplication.MainActivity` is an odd choice at best).

If you create a new project, when it asks for the package name, fill in `com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample` to match the tutorial.

However, do bear in mind that the "tutorials" that you are following are incomplete, skipping steps along the way. Despite their name, most of those "tutorials" are not suited for newcomers to Android.